# React-router v1.0; Passing props into application on server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

In react-router 0.13, you could pass props into a route handler, as such

```
serverApp.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  Router.run(AppRoutes, req.url, function(Handler, state) {
    var markup = React.renderToString(
      <Handler path={req.url} myProps={myProps}/>
    );
    res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + markup);
  });
});
```

Now with react-router v1.0, that has been replaced with `match()` and `RoutingContext`. I have not been able to get it to work. My code below:

```
serverApp.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  match({routes: AppRoutes, location: req.url},
    (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      var markup;

      if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
      } else if (redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      } else if (renderProps) {
        var myApp = React.cloneElement(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />, {myProps: 'OK'});
        markup = renderToString(myApp);
        res.status(200).send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + markup);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

This is what I thought should work, but having no success. I test it by logging out the additional prop in the render method of the component, as well as setting it in an h1 tag.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?
Much appreciated.

Related: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1369

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a method `createElement` to `RoutingContext`. In the `createElement` method you have access to the component that will be returned. Here you can add external props that will be available to every route that mounted.

Server:

```
serverApp.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  match({routes: AppRoutes, location: req.url},
    (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      var markup;
      var myApp;
      var createElement = function(Component, props) {
        return <Component {...props} myProps="OK"/>;
      };

      if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
      } else if (redirectLocation) {
        res.redirect(302,
          redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      } else if (renderProps) {
        myApp = (
          <RoutingContext
            {...renderProps}
            createElement={createElement}
          />
        );
        markup = renderToString(myApp);
        res.status(200).send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + markup);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

React app routes:

```
var AppRoutes = (
  <Route component={AppTemplate} path="/">
    <Route component={OtherTemplate} path="/">
      <Route component={FirstPage} path="/first" />
    <Route />
  <Route />
);
```

When navigating to '/first', all 3 of those components will have access to myProps via `this.props.myProps`

The more practical use case for this is passing a flux object into your application (instead of a simple myProps="OK").