# React Router server rendering with server props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[Here's an example from the docs.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md)

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'

serve((req, res) => {
  // Note that req.url here should be the full URL path from
  // the original request, including the query string.
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
      // You can also check renderProps.components or renderProps.routes for
      // your "not found" component or route respectively, and send a 404 as
      // below, if you're using a catch-all route.
      res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />))
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  })
})
```

I have an object like this:

```
let reactServerProps = {
  'gaKey': process.env.GA_KEY,
  'query': req.query,
}
```

I'm trying to pass this object into react router here

```
res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} {...reactServerProps} />))
```

And I can't seem to provide access to the variables from within my components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `<ReactContext />` only passes some react-router pre-defined props down to the component tree that it builds rather than the custom props you might expect in a normal component.

There are a few workarounds to this issue, though none of them are particularly pretty. The most widely used I think I've seen is to wrap `<ReactContext />` with a component whose sole purpose is to make use of React's context feature & pass contextual data down to its children rather than props.

So:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class DataWrapper extends React.Component {

getChildContext () {

    return {
        data: this.props.data
    };

}

render () {

    return this.props.children;
}
}
```

Then in your express server:

```
// Grab the data from wherever you need then pass it to your <DataWrapper /> as a prop 
// which in turn will pass it down to all it's children through context
res.status(200).send(renderToString(<DataWrapper data={data}><RouterContext {...renderProps} /></DataWrapper>))
```

And you should then be able to access that data in your child components:

```
export default class SomeChildComponent extends React.Component {

constructor (props, context) {

    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        gaKey: context.data.gaKey,
        query: context.data.query
    };
}

};
```

I know it used to be possible to make use of the `createElement` method to set some custom props and pass them through to your child routes in a similar fashion, but I'm not positive that's still valid in newer versions of react-router. See: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1369

---

**UPDATE:** It is still possible to use middleware to pass additional values into route components. via: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3183

And you should be able to make use of props over context:

```
function createElementFn(serverProps) {
  return function(Component, props) {
    return <Component {...serverProps} {...props} />
  }
}
```

Then add `createElement` in your `<RouterContext />` like so, passing it your serverProps:

```
res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} createElement={createElementFn(serverProps)} />))
```

And access them in any of your child components with a simple `this.props.gaKey` & `this.props.query`

Comment: I already have all my components wired up using the `props` namespace looking for variables. Is there any way I can pass data as `props`?

Comment: You could take a crack at the createElement method, I found one implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978781. Though again, I'm not positive that's worked since react-router v1.

I think it's also possible, though it feels pretty hacky, to use the Object `assign()` method to inject your data directly into `renderProps`. ie) `assign(renderProps.params, reactServerProps)`

Comment: @ThomasReggi Good news, seems it's still perfectly viable to pass values down as props to all the children rather than context. Updated the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to look deeper into this!

Comment: I have a problem with it. the props.query for example is flashing for a second and then disappears.. what is wrong with it?

Answer (score -1):

A much simpler solution is to put whatever data you want in `props.routes` and it will be passed to your component where you can access it directly through

`props.routes.[whatever you passed in]`

So in the serve function you can do

```
props.routes.reactServerProps = {
'gaKey': process.env.GA_KEY,
'query': req.query
}
```

and in your component you can access it with `props.routes.reactServerProps`.

See the very last comment by Ryan Florence.  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1017

He forgot the (s). Won't work with route.